# regular expression put space between number and character

Tags: regex, node.js

I wonder how can I write regular expression to put a space between number and character only if this character not % and not space.

```
var str = "... 15a...".replace(/(\d+)(\D+)/g,'$1 $2')
```

The above doesn't work as I expect, for example I need the following constraints

```
"... 15a ..." => "... 15 a ..."
"... 15 a ..." => "... 15 a ..."
"... 15% ..." => "... 15% ..."
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "... 15a...".replace(/(\d+)([a-z]+)/g,'$1 $2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"... 15a...".replace(/(\d+)([^%\d\s]+?)/g,'$1 $2')
```

"... 15 a..."

> "... 15 a...".replace(/(\d+)([^%\d\s]+?)/g,'$1 $2')

"... 15 a..."

> "... 15%...".replace(/(\d+)([^%\d\s]+?)/g,'$1 $2')

"... 15%..."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to find a digit followed by a nondigit, non-percent character. So this:

```
replace(/(\d)([^\d\s%])/g,'$1 $2')
```

Should do the trick.